# tapestry. output of Date

Tags: java, tapestry

how to do?

```
<t:output format="literal:dd.MM.yyyy" value="myItem.activity.do_create_date"/>
```

I want to know how to format output of date?

Comment: Thanks for your question: in contains answer to my question :)

Answer (score 7):

What you have works (in Tapestry 5.2.4). What problem are you having or what more specifically are you trying to do? If you want to get the format from your Java class, here's are example snippets.

**.java file:**

```
private String format;
private Date date;

public void setupRender() {
    // just an example
    format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
    date = new Date();
}

public String getFormat() {
    return format;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

**.tml file:**

```
<t:output format="format" value="date" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found that most apps have specific, uniform ways to format dates; I usually create a OutputDate component that encapsulates formatting and other concerns.

Answer (score 3):

**page template:**

```
<t:output format="format" value="myItem.activity.do_create_date"/>
```

**page class:**

```
private final String format = "dd.MM.yyyy";

public Format getFormat()
{
    return new SimpleDateFormat(format);
}
```